# how to display content of a file upload control in a label just by browsing it & without clicking a button without help of AJAX

Tags: asp.net

I have a file upload control without upload button & a label in a page. I want to display the content of file upload control in that label just after browsing the file upload control.I want to do this without help of AJAX.So how to do this ? Can anyone kindly help me ? Please write the code using C# language not in VB.

Answer (score 0):

The content - do you mean the filepath or the contents of the file?

Comment: I mean the filepath.Please help me brother.

Comment: Just after browsing you will be on the client side, so I think you'll want to do this with javascript rather than a server side language.

Comment: So,please tell me how to do this with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

As file upload input element doesn't emit events (well it might, but that is not standard), the only way to get the desirable behavior is to monitor its value.

Example:

```
<form id="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" size="20" id="targetLabelForUpload"><br />
Age: <input type="text" size="20"><br />
File: <input type="file" size="20" id="uploadSource"><br />
</form>

<script>
function checkValue() {
document.getElementById("targetLabelForUpload").value=
document.getElementById("uploadSource").value;
}
setInterval(checkValue, 1000);
</script>
```

This script updates "Name" input box once in a while with file name from "File".
Beware: the is usually no path information in "value" property of file input, only a filename. This is a security issue, i think.

Comment: Sorry,friend this code doesn't satisfy my criteria,because u r using a button.My need is that "no buttons should be used".

Answer (score 0):

The filepath isn't exposed through JavaScript (certainly not in the most recent versions of browsers). This is a security feature of the language.

Comment: I don't think you can. You'd need to use AJAX to post the form back to the server, and return the image through a url - possibly using an HttpHandler or similar.